# Parsing text with C# Regex

Tags: c#, regex

I am developing a text editor for a game project. We have a few types of tagging rules.

Here are some examples:

`[k1]Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet[/k1]` (a sentence with 'k1' tag)

`[k1k2]Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet[/k1k2]`  (a sentence which has 'k1' and 'k2' tags)

`[k1!k2]Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet[/k1!k2]` (a sentence which has k1 tag but not k2)

In a long text, I must realize any sentence belonging or restricted by multiple tags between k1 to k9. This is also possible:

`[k1k2k3!k4!k5]Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet[/k1k2k3!k4!k5]`

So what type of regex should I use to parse matching sentences?

Edit:

So here is a solid scenario. I have a paragraph like this:

`[k1]This is a Sentence 1.[/k1][k1k2]Another Sentence 2[/k1k2][k1!k2]And the 3rd sentence.[/k1!k2][k1k2k3!k4!k5]The last sentence[/k1k2k3!k4!k5]`

So if a user has both k1 and k3 tags, what she must see is:

`This is a Sentence 1. And the 3rd sentence.`

Comment: Well, in your example all you need to do is look in the opening `[]` tag, which returns (say) `k1k2k3!k4!k5` - you don't need a regular expression to parse that, you can just go through the result and extract the `k` values.

Comment: .. although reading your question again, you say _what type of regex should I use to parse matching sentences?_ - you mean sentences which have the same tags within a longer text? Can you show an example of that?

Comment: Ok let me give you a solid example.

Comment: Think all the text here as a whole paragraph like: [k1]Sentence 1[/k1][k1k2]Sentence 2[/k1k2][k1!k2]Sentence3[/k1!k2][k1k2k3!k4!k5]Sentence 4[/k1k2k3!k4!k5]

In my game, if a user has k1 tag and k2 tag, she can only see this paragraph as "Sentence 1. Sentence 2."

Comment: (Don't get me wrong, regexes are great when you need them, but _"Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems."_)

Comment: You need to edit your example in your question so people can see it clearly, along with the expected results.

Comment: @stuartd I edited and tried to explain it more. Do you still think same way?

Comment: OK, so this is how I see the problem. 1) You need to extract each sentence and its containing tags 2) You need to parse the tags (by whatever means) and 3) You need to determine from the tag parse whether a user can see the sentence. So - yes, I think it's easier just to parse the tags than to use a regular expression.

Comment: There are amazing people here on SO who can write a regex to parse almost anything, and they've helped me a lot in the past, and I've learned a lot from them. I don't think though that using a regular expression is the best strategy for what you need to do, though I'm sure it's possible - but then you might have a really complicated regex, rather than some comparatively simple, understandable, and maintainable code.

Comment: Maybe `\[(.*?)\](.*?)\[` is enough. In `Group[1]` you have the Tags and in `Group[2]` the related Sentence. Then use LINQ on the Matches collection to determine what a specific *User* can *see* (i.e., return `Group[2].Value` `Where` `Group[1].Value` contains the User's Tags unless the Tag is prefixed by `!`).

Comment: @dreamend, your "solid" scenario is a bit unclear to me: `This is a Sentence 1.` is tagged as `k1` only, `Another Sentence 2` is tagged as `k1k2`, `And the 3rd sentence.` is tagged `k1!k2`, so the three of them are the same with respect to `k1` and `k3`. However you say that _if a user has both `k1` and `k3` tags_, only the first and third sentences are taken. Can you explain a bit better why? Also, if `[k1k2]` means "has both tags", and `[k1!k2]` means "has tag `k1`, has not tag `k2`", what does `[k1]` mean? "Has `k1`, but I've no clue about `k2`"?

Comment: Last but not least, the conditional _if a user has blablabla_ implies that you need a "parametric regex", I mean something which you give a parameter (e.g. the list of tags of a given user) to, and it "instantiates" a regex and uses it to extract something.

Comment: Hi @EnricoMariaDeAngelis. What you understand is 100% true. k1k2 means user have both tags while k1!k2 means it will be shown only if user has k1 but not k2.

Comment: @dreamend, than how does `k1k2` differ from the simple `k1`? Please, answer the question.

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis k1k2 is simply a k1&&k2 so both must be true for user.

Comment: @dreamend, last time I ask the same question without getting an answer: if `[k1k2]` means a user must have both `k1` and `k2`, and `[k1!k2]` means a user must have `k1` must **not** have `k2`, what does `[k1]` alone mean? Yes, the user must have `k1`, but what about `k2`?

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis omg..I think you are focusing on the wrong question. Think it as a 3 state condition k1 means true !k1 means false and lack of something means (for example lack of k2)  UNKNOWN. There's a finite set of k1,k2,k3. If we see a k1 tag, that means we dont have an idea about k2,k3,k4. But when we see k1!k2, it means we 'explored' k2 but it's false.  

But please. It's not so much important for that question I think. You can think the example as [k1!k3]

Comment: @dreamend, in your example the user who has `k1` and `k3` sees `This is a Sentence 1. And the 3rd sentence.`, but not `The last sentence`. Why?

Comment: Because last sentence has k1,k2,k3,!k4,!k5. It's an AND operation so user must have k1,k2,k3,not k4,not k5 tags